# Не появляются ToolTip в QTableView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Есть таблица, в которой есть ячейка с датой рождения. Хочу чтобы при выборе определенной строки колонке с датой добавлялся тултип, определяющий возраст.

Сначала попытался просто добавить тултипы в цикле, чтобы проверить их - они не работают. 
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

```
class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(mainWindow, self).__init__()
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.database = newDatabase()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
    self.model.setTable("handbook")
    self.model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
    self.model.select()
    self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.model)
    self.ui.tableView.setAttribute(Qt.WA_AlwaysShowToolTips,True)
    #self.ui.tableView.setColumnHidden(0, True)

    for rowI in range(self.model.rowCount()):
        self.model.setData(self.model.index(rowI,4),"lol",Qt.ToolTipRole)

    self.ui.deleteButton.clicked.connect(self.showDeleteDialog)
    self.showDeleteDialogFlag = True
    self.ui.addButton.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.showAddorEditDialog,'add'))
    self.ui.editButton.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.showAddorEditDialog,'edit'))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вы не публикуете минимальный пример, который можно воспроизвести, поэтому я покажу абстрактный пример, который должен вам помочь.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class PaletteListModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, colors = [], parent = None):
        QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.__colors = colors

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__colors)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return "Palette"
            else:
                return "Color {}".format(section)

        if role == Qt.ToolTipRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return "Horizontal Header {} Tooltip".format(section)
            else:
                return "Vertical Header {} Tooltip".format(section)

    def data(self, index, role):
        row = index.row()
        value = self.__colors[row]

        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            return self.__colors[row].name()

        # add a tooltip
        if role == Qt.ToolTipRole:
            return "Hex code: {}".format(value.name())

        if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
            pixmap = QPixmap(26,26)
            pixmap.fill(value)
            icon = QIcon(pixmap)
            return icon

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return value.name()

    def setData(self, index, value, role = Qt.EditRole):
        row = index.row()
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            color = QColor(value)
            if color.isValid():
                self.__colors[row] = color
                self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
                return True

        return False

    # implment flags() method
    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    tableView = QTableView()
    red   = QColor(255,0,0)
    green = QColor(0,255,0)
    blue  = QColor(0,0,255)

    model = PaletteListModel([red, green, blue])
    tableView.setModel(model)
    tableView.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]